# Why are derivatives markets the most fragile in times of correction?

Tags: options, stock-markets, futures, cryptocurrency

I read an [article](https://themarket.ch/meinung/bitcoin-the-derivative-bomb-ld.3398) about bitcoin derivatives which has been skyrocketing lately. The author wrote at the end of the article:

> Derivatives markets are the most fragile in times of correction,
> triggering a cascade of liquidations, as was seen on March 12, 2020
> («Black Thursday») when several funds had to close shop. At that time,
> several billion dollars worth of outstanding derivative contracts had
> to be marked-to-market in real time (real-time margining) and rapidly
> liquidated in the midst of free-falling spot prices, with only tens of
> millions of dollars of liquidity.

I don't really understand the mechanics of what was written. Can someone please explain to me what (and why) are the liquidity dangers of derivatives at times of corrections/volatility?

Comment: Why? It is obvious - derivatives are there for leveraged trading. Leverage ALSO means higher risk (as well as higher rewards). As such, any movement (and corrections tend to be more violent than upward moves) will trigger a lot of liquidations when people run out of margin. It is obvious - many players using les than 100% capitalization.

Comment: Same post on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/options/comments/kv2zx4/options_questions_safe_haven_thread_jan_1117_2021/gjjzv8k/

Answer (score 1):

If the derivatives are OTC, and are highly leveraged, then you can have a confluence of (relatively) low liquidity, and rapidly escalating losses against the only counterparty that can help you exit the position. In that cases, action is usually taken very rapidly!